# How do I run an encryption program multiple times to strengthen the encode?

Tags: loops, encryption, for-loop, decode, encode

Here is my code so far. I need to run the encode part of the code 5 times and then decode the encode the same number of times. I figured out how to encode the message but now I can't figure out how to run the "encode" or "decode" variable back through the code to strengthen the ecryption.

```
public class Codes
    {
        /**
         * Encode and decode a message using a key of values stored in
         * a queue.
         */
        public static void main(String[] args)
        { 
            int[] key = {7, 6, 5, 2, 8, 5, 8, 6, 4, 1};
            Integer keyValue;
            String encoded = "", decoded = "";
            String message = "Queues are useful for encoding messages.";
            Queue<Integer> encodingQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            Queue<Integer> decodingQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();

            // load key queues 
            for (int scan = 0; scan < key.length; scan++)
            {
                encodingQueue.add(key[scan]);
                decodingQueue.add(key[scan]);
            }

            // encode message
            for (int scan = 0; scan < message.length(); scan++)
            {
                keyValue = encodingQueue.remove();
                encoded += (char) (message.charAt(scan) + keyValue);
                encodingQueue.add(keyValue);
            }

            System.out.println ("Encoded Message:\n" + encoded + "\n");


            // decode message 
            for (int scan = 0; scan < encoded.length(); scan++)
            {
                keyValue = decodingQueue.remove();
                decoded += (char) (encoded.charAt(scan) - keyValue);
                decodingQueue.add(keyValue);
            }

            System.out.println ("Decoded Message:\n" + decoded);
        }


    }
```

as of right now I am receiving this output:

```
Encoded Message:
X{jwmx(gvf'{xgnzt&jpy&jpktlorh'sju{fokw/

Decoded Message:
Queues are useful for encoding messages.
```

In order to complete this program I need the output to look like this:

```
Encoded Message 1: X{jwmx(gvf'{xgnzt&jpy&jpktlorh'sju{fokw/ 
Encoded Message 2: _?oyu}0mzg.?}iv•|,nq?,orsytuvi.yow?kwq{0 
Encoded Message 3: f?t{}?8s~h5??k~??2rr?2tt{~|{zj5•ty?p•w•1 
Encoded Message 4: m?y}??@y?i<??m???8vs?8yv????~k<?y{?u?}?2 
Encoded Message 5: t?~•??H•?jC??o???>zt?>~x?????lC?~}?z???3 
Decoded Message 5: m?y}??@y?i<??m???8vs?8yv????~k<?y{?u?}?2 
Decoded Message 4: f?t{}?8s~h5??k~??2rr?2tt{~|{zj5•ty?p•w•1 
Decoded Message 3: _?oyu}0mzg.?}iv•|,nq?,orsytuvi.yow?kwq{0 
Decoded Message 2: X{jwmx(gvf'{xgnzt&jpy&jpktlorh'sju{fokw/ 
Decoded Message 1: Queues are useful for encoding messages.
```

I estimate that in order to make this happen I need to use a loop to run the "encode" and "decode" variables back through the program. However I cannot figure out how to make that happen.

Comment: Please give a bit of background. Tell what you expect, and why, and what you are getting. Else we are going to stare at the code all day just to conclude that it is doing what is written there.

Comment: You're not actually strengthening anything by running the algorithm multiple times.  All it's doing is adding a constant to each character, and if you do that multiple times, you're just changing which constant is effectively added.  For example:  you encrypt the first letter by adding 7, then you encrypt the result by adding 7 again.  You could accomplish the same thing by just adding 14 once.

Comment: I had mis-read your code when I gave my answer; I hope my update is more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This will be easier if you use separate functions for the `encode()` and `decode()` operations:

```
class Codes {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
  }

  private static String encode(String plaintext, Queue<Integer> encodingQueue) {
    ...
  }

  private static String decode(String ciphertext, Queue<Integer> decodingQueue) {
    ...
  }

}
```

Does that help?